# tensorflow model gives "graph disconnected" error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am experimenting/fiddling/learning with some small ML problems.

I have a loaded model based on a pre-trained convolution base with some self-trained dense layers (for model details see below).

I wanted to try to apply some visualizations like activations and the Grad CAM Visualization (https://www.statworx.com/de/blog/erklaerbbarkeit-von-deep-learning-modellen-mit-grad-cam/) on the model. But I was not able to do so.

I tried to create a new model based on mine (like in the article) with

```
grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(model.inputs,
                                   [model.get_layer('vgg16').output,
                                    model.output])
```

but this already fails with the error:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_5_12:0", shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "block1_conv1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

I do not understand what this means. the model surely works (i can evaluate it and make predictions with it).
The call does not fail if I omit the `model.get_layer('vgg16').output` from the outputs list but of course, this is required for the visualization.

What I am doing wrong?

In a model that I constructed and trained from scratch, I was able to create a similar model with the activations as outputs but here i get these errors.

### My model's details

The model was created with the following code and then trained and saved.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers


conv_base  = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(
    weights="vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5",
    include_top=False)
conv_base.trainable = False
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
        layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.1),
        layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.2),
    ]
)

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(180, 180, 3))
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = conv_base(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(256)(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer="rmsprop",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

later it was loaded:

```
model = keras.models.load_model("myModel.keras")
print(model.summary())
print(model.get_layer('sequential').summary())
print(model.get_layer('vgg16').summary())
```

output:

```
Model: "functional_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)         [(None, 180, 180, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
sequential (Sequential)      (None, 180, 180, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
vgg16 (Functional)           (None, None, None, 512)   14714688  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 12800)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 256)               3277056   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
Total params: 17,992,001
Trainable params: 10,356,737
Non-trainable params: 7,635,264
_________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
random_flip (RandomFlip)     (None, 180, 180, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
random_rotation (RandomRotat (None, 180, 180, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
random_zoom (RandomZoom)     (None, 180, 180, 3)       0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "vgg16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         [(None, None, None, 3)]   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        multiple                  1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        multiple                  36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        multiple                  73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        multiple                  147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        multiple                  295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        multiple                  590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        multiple                  590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        multiple                  1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        multiple                  2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        multiple                  2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        multiple                  2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        multiple                  2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        multiple                  2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   multiple                  0         
=================================================================
Total params: 14,714,688
Trainable params: 7,079,424
Non-trainable params: 7,635,264
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want in the following way. First, define your model as follows:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(180, 180, 3))
x = data_augmentation(inputs, training=True)
x = keras.applications.VGG16(input_tensor=x,
                               include_top=False,
                               weights=None)
x.trainable = False
x = layers.Flatten()(x.output)
x = layers.Dense(256)(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, x)

for i, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    print(i, layer.name, layer.output_shape, layer.trainable)
```

```
...
17 block5_conv2 (None, 11, 11, 512) False
18 block5_conv3 (None, 11, 11, 512) False
19 block5_pool (None, 5, 5, 512) False
20 flatten_2 (None, 12800) True
21 dense_4 (None, 256) True
22 dropout_2 (None, 256) True
23 dense_5 (None, 1) True
```

Now, build the grad-cam model with desired output layer as follows:

```
grad_model = keras.models.Model(
    [model.inputs], 
    [model.get_layer('block5_pool').output, 
     model.output]
)
```

**Test**

```
image = np.random.rand(1, 180, 180, 3).astype(np.float32) 

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    convOutputs, predictions = grad_model(tf.cast(image, tf.float32))
    loss = predictions[:, tf.argmax(predictions[0])]

grads = tape.gradient(loss, convOutputs)
print(grads)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[[ 9.8454033e-04  3.6991197e-03 ... -1.2012678e-02
    -1.7934230e-03  2.2925171e-03]
   [ 1.6165405e-03 -1.9513096e-03 ... -2.5789393e-03
     1.2443252e-03 -1.3931725e-03]
   [-2.0554627e-04  1.2232144e-03 ...  5.2324748e-03
     3.1955825e-04  3.4566019e-03]
   [ 2.3650150e-03 -2.5699558e-03 ... -2.4103196e-03
     5.8940407e-03  5.3285398e-03]

...
```

Comment: can you please explain, what happened on my model and what and how it is different? I mean, I could train and use it...

Comment: and is it possible to get it working and still have the pretrained parts within a sub model or sub layers (or however the nomenclature for this is)

Comment: In your model, the `vgg` is somewhat acting as a single layer. Maybe that's why you got the graph disconnected. Again, even if you pass an input tensor to vgg, you may be able to build a grad-cam model but again you probably would face None output from  `tape.gradient` because of the feature that comes from the input layer (here in your case which is `vgg`.